# Accessing a specific sequence type within a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, set, sequence

I'm trying to access/filter for sets within a 2D numpy array.

The array looks something like this

```
[[1,2,3,{1,2,3,4},]
[{5,4,6,7},4,5,7]]
```

I thought initially I'd be able to use `np.size` to filter for the sets (assuming sets have a size higher than `1`).

However, the size of the sets returned `1`, the same as the individual elements within the array.

I've also tried using `np.where.(array==set.....` but this did not filter for the sets either.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't sound like you should be using Numpy for that kind of task in the first place. What is the bigger picture? Why not use lists instead?

Comment: Did you read the docs tor `np.size`?  `size` gives the number of elements in the array.  Assuming this is a (2,4) object dtype array, it has 8 elements.

Comment: `np.where` is only as good as its condition.  `array==set` tries to compare the elements of the array to the `class/function` `set`.

Comment: The purpose of using numpy is so that I can loop through the array quicker.